# How do I append WordPress category ID to image URL in my code?

Tags: image, wordpress, categories

I am coding a page that lists all of my categories, along with an image associated with that category. So far I am using this to create my list:

```
    <?php 
        $args=array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'order' => 'ASC'
          );
        $categories=get_categories($args);
        ?>  

        <ul id="category-list-grid">
            <?php
            foreach($categories as $cat) {
            ?>
                <li><?php echo "<a href='" . get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) . "'> $cat->cat_name </a>"  ?></li>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

It works like a charm and displays a list of text links to each category. I want to take it one step further though and assign an image. Each image follows this naming convention:

category-[id].jpg (minus the brackets, of course)

I know *what* I need to do, just not *how* to do it. I want to add `<img src="category-[code to insert cat id].jpg" border="0">`

How do I do this? I am trying to avoid using a plugin as I am trying to keep the site as streamlined as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<img src="category-<?php echo $cat->cat_ID; ?>.jpg" border="0"/>
```

Edit to show full requested code:

```
<ul id="category-list-grid">
<?php foreach($categories as $cat){ ?>
    <li>
       <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->cat_ID); ?>">
       <?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>
       </a>
       <img src="category-<?php echo $cat->cat_ID; ?>.jpg" border="0"/>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This isn't working - I know it has to do w/ the extra echo in my code, but how do I fix it? <li><?php echo "<a href='" . get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) . "'><img src='"/images/category-<?php echo $cat->cat_ID; ?>.jpg"' border='"0"' /> $cat->cat_name </a>"  ?></li>